# Is there a way to make a counter that doesn't restart every time i refresh the website page

Tags: javascript, html

So I've created a counter that adds 40 every specific time (e.g. every second).
I want to keep it as it is right now but find a way to not make it restart every time I refresh the page.

The code is:

```
 <div class="baseNum" id="baseNum"> base number = 1000</div>
   <div class="resultContainer" id="resultContainer">
    after every sec + 40 = <span class="result" id="result"></span>
  </div>
  

    var resultDisplay = document.getElementById("result");
    
    var baseNum = 1000;
    var add = 40;
    var time = 24 * 3600000; // change the 24 to any hours you want
    
    resultDisplay.innerHTML = baseNum;
    
    function add40() {
    
        setTimeout(() => {
            resultDisplay.innerHTML = baseNum;
    
            if (baseNum !== 0) {
                baseNum += 40;
            } add40()
        }, time);
    } add40();
```

I'm using Wordpress for a client with Elementor, if you guys maybe know an alternative in this environment.
Thank you!

Comment: You are either looking into server-sided programming or must utilize `localStorage` / `sessionStorage` or `cookies` . To both methods, you find plenty of duplicates here.

Comment: Yeah but, I need that the number must be the same to anyone that log in the website

Comment: then you require server-sided programming and need to return the value from the client side. It cant be done by default. A website is just a textile that is downloaded to the browser's cache and then displayed. Any changes made there are only local and as such not available to other users. This means you not just require a webserver for deployment but also a server sided logic and storing method (such as a database).